# C++ Builder XE5 - How to turn off Deployment Manager

Tags: deployment, ide, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I apologize if this is not the right place to ask such question, but I'm at my wit's end since Embarcadero's forum won't allow me to post any question there.

I have enabled the "Deploy" feature in the C++ Builder IDE, to test out about the depending dll & bpl files of my application, when I'm done, I found myself trapped in an annoying state - I can't perform any debugging without connected to a remote pc (with their PAServer)! This is causing a HUGE problem for me as I will not be able to debug my application if I'm away from the office, i.e. I'm on a field service at my client's place or at home.

I tried deleting the deployment profile, but it just get recreated every-time I compile my project and there is a DEPLOY command upon running compiling and running the source code. I have to wait until the connection attempt to the remote pc time-out to continue testing the application by manually clicking the .exe of my application.

Is there any way to turn off the "Deploy" feature so that I can do debugging on my local machine just as before activating the "Deploy" feature?

Comment: `http://forums.embarcadero.com`, `nntp://forums.embarcadero.com`, and `http://community.embarcadero.com/answers/` work just fine. When posting, are you logged in to your EDN account?

Comment: Yes, I did logged in when I last visit the forums, but oddly, I was not allowed to post anything... Is there any "approval" process needed before a new user can post? Anyway, I can post questions in the Embarcadero forum now.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found out where the profile was hiding and deleted it, now I can debug as usual.

In the Rad Studio help:
ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe5/rad/Connection_Profile_Manager.html

Answer (score 0):

On occasion, I have this same problem with DelphiXE5 (*where the problem is that I forget how to get back to the default environment without losing my remote settings.*)

- **Remote Deploy active**:
   [image: Remote Deploy mode]
- **The Revert option for the *normal* build/debug environment**:
  [image]
- **And finally, the previous Remote Deploy settings available via the same Target Platform context menu (i.e., Properties):**
  [image]

The *Default Connection* isn't something to be setup. To the contrary, it's really not a connection at all. The *Revert...* menu item essentially means *Revert to local build & debug*.